# How I can make QtCreator to have an Ogre project

Tags: qt, qt4, qt-creator, ogre3d, ogre

As in the title, how I can make QtCreator to have an Ogre project when creating a new project, see the image http://imagebin.org/172549

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a project wizard:
http://doc.qt.nokia.com/qtcreator-snapshot/creator-project-wizards.html